# Making a responsive button between mobile and desktop devices

Tags: html, css, button, responsive

I have a simple task, make a button that is always centered. What is the best approach, can it be done simply?

So far, I have made a blue button, but for some reason when I go height 100%, width 100%, it is not filling up the entire screen. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfa1r.jpg, why would the html body not be default to be 100% of the page?

Code so far:

Style.css, using an angular project.

```
.body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

app.component.ts 
`<button class="button button5"> </button>`

app.component.css

```
.button {
    background-color: #0066ff;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.button5 {border-radius: 50%;}
```

I expected my button to take up the entire page, as it's parent. (body) should be 100% of the page.

Comment: First, provide us with code you already have (not just pictures). Second, post the image as image, not as link, it'd make the question more readable.

Comment: Set the body element height to 100%

Comment: @doppl3r Code added now, I think I have done that. Is it meant to be in style.css?

Comment: I have no idea why I'm writing a button to be 100%, but here is your code to accomplish this trivial task: https://codepen.io/doppl3r/pen/VyxQer

Comment: @doppl3r what a beaut :D

Comment: unless you have a wrapper `<div class="body"></div>` your css selector should be `body {}` not `.body {}` (notice the extra `.`)

Answer (score 1):

Centering a button on the page is relatively simple if you use flex-box

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.button {
  background-color: #838383;
  color: #fefefe;
  padding: 16px;
  /* ...if you really want it to be 100% of the screen un-comment below */
/*   height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; */
}
```

```html
<button class="button"> I am a centered button </button>
```

Comment: Lol did my edit make this post active, I just got annoyed seeing the type-o I made. I solved the solution using viewports, they're so useful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the simple (yet not recommended `<center>` tag? I use it all the time. Works just fine.

If not, you can use `margin-left: calc(50% - 50px);` If the image is 100px wide.  You can use `text-align:center;` or `align:center;`